# Invoking the post action of JSP (which uses Spring MVC) from the PHP form

Tags: php, spring, jsp, post, spring-mvc

Currently I am using Spring MVC architecture having JSP as a VIEW.  At present, the website is build with PHP .

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User Name :</td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I need to invoke the above JSP  Post function from PHP page and retrieve the result back to the PHP page. How can I achieve this?

Help.Please.

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve the result back" to the PHP page? What kind of result?

Comment: i mean the result of Java  which the JSP page calls. It is the collection of Object.

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of ways to deal with your situation, the simplest way is that in the action jsp or servlet, create a URLConnection to retrieve the result:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://domain.com/something.php");
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> entrySet = headers.entrySet();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : entrySet) {
        String headerName = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println("Header Name:" + headerName);
        List<String> headerValues = entry.getValue();
        for (String value : headerValues) {
            System.out.print("Header value:" + value);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The another way is using ajax for your request, you don't need to start from scratch but using one of well known framework such as jquery or extjs ...

Using extjs you can request to php page:

```
yourform.doAction('submit',
{
    url: 'something.php',
    success: function(form, action) 
    {
        //To do: when success
    },
    failure: function(form, action) 
    {

    }
});
```

Enjoy coding!

Comment: I mean. calling JSP page from PHP page. the PHP page contains the form. When user clicks submit button on PHP page, it should call the JSP form submit method and then call the form (post submit operation) . In my case I am using SPRING MVC